# How do I prioritize search results to show file names containing keyword appear first?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, query

I have a document library in sharepoint online and I need to have the search results show any documents that have the searched keyword appear in the file name come up first in results, (i.e. if I have a document called "Test Document", and someone searched "Test" it should be one of the first results. I've been trying to get this to work using a query rule but nothing I do fixes this issue.

Comment: What query are you using in your Query Rule? What have you tried? I would look at adding a content boost to XRank. It is easier than changing the ranking model. Update your questions and I'll dig around and test a sample.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I made it so there are no Query Conditions and then when building the query I sort by Rank and then I change ranking when Title matches keyword and promote it to top. Sorry if I'm not being more descriptive, it's my first time working with sharepoint.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Do you have anything like "Name:{SearchBoxQuery}" in your query? Content boost is powerful to prioritize certain results, but "Name:{SearchBoxQuery}" should get you there as a start.

Comment: Name and Title are actually 2 different managed properties

Comment: @YogaPanda what do you mean? The query builder seems absurdly convoluted, I don't really know how to use it properly

Comment: @Courtez can you paste your query?

Answer (score 0):

Promote certain results (or the other two options listed):
http://icansharepoint.com/3-simple-things-it-can-do-to-improve-sharepoint-search/ 
Promote Results will set certain keywords to show certain documents first.

Make sure your users know how to properly search for information; it's not 100% like googling:
http://icansharepoint.com/infographic-search-sharepoint/ 
and more on searching:
http://icansharepoint.com/how-to-improve-your-sharepoint-search-results/